# How to prevent socket.listen getting called asynchronously in dart

Tags: flutter, file, dart, sockets

**Question**
I am working on a flutter project that uses dart sockets to transfer files from a logger device to the app. I have successfully done this using the `socket.onListen` method and the `socket.write` command. In the socket.listen, I write the data into a file and name it. However, if I loop through like 100 times and do a `socket.write('command $i')`, the onListen does not get call respectively for each file and I believe the files end up getting clumped up. I am wondering if there is a way to make sure each `socket.write` command gets its on call to `socket.listen` call. I have looked through at least 50 stack overflow questions and nothing is working for me. Here is my code

```
int count = 0;
sock = await Socket.connect('192.168.4.1', 25443);

sock.listen((Uint8List data) async {
    print('Data at $count' + data.toString());
    File f = await _localFile(count);
    f.writeAsBytes(data);
});

for(int i =0; i < fileSize; i++){
   sock.write('transfer $i');
   count++;
}
```

**Output**
`Data at 0[19, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 119, 105, 98, 108, 45, 49, 11, 0, 0, 0, 85, 83, 67, 71, 67, 45, 72, 101, 97, 108, 121, 13, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 100, 101, 100, 117, 112, 4, 0, 0, 0, 78, 111, 110, 101, 14, 0, 0, 0, 185, 2, 0, 0, 181, 2, 0, 0, 123, 32, 34, 112, 108, 97, 116, 102, 111, 114, 109, 34, 58, 32, 123, 32, 34, 117, 110, 105, 113, 117, 101, 73, 68, 34, 58, 32, 34, 119, 105, 98, 108, 45, 49, 34, 44, 32, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 83, 104, 105, 112, 34, 44, 32, 34, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 85, 83, 67, 71, 67, 32, 72, 101, 97, 108, 121, 34, 44, 32, 34, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 34, 58, 32, 49, 50, 56, 44, 32, 34, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 85, 110, 105, 116, 79, 102, 77, 101, 97, 115, 117, 114, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 109, 101, 116, 114, 101, 34, 44, 32, 34, 73, 68, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 73, 77, 79, 34, 44, 32, 34, 73, 68, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 3`

It ends there, it does not go onto the other files.

Is there something I am missing? I am open to other ideas to attack this problem as well.

Comment: You can't. TCP doesn't work that way.

Comment: So then is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: yes, the approach is to write your problem so it's okay with receiving any number of bytes

Comment: but i am okay with this, I just never get the correct amount of bytes

Comment: You can't get the correct amount of bytes. It's up to you to make sure your program still works no matter how many bytes you get